# How can I use the Except Exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception, printing, except

I need to make a code that doesn't give me an error, I want a print to try again for example.

I learn in other topics, but I don't understand anything about that.
I have this code:

```
def conversor(anosluz):
    try:
        km = float(anosluz * (9.459 * 10**12)) 
        return km
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Ooops! O valor que inseriste nao e o correcto, tenta de novo.', e


if __name__=='__main__':
    anosluz = input('Insira a distancia em anos luz: ')
    resultado = conversor(anosluz)
    print resultado
```

Comment: What part of it do you not understand? This code appears to work already.

Comment: But doesn't work! I want that, when I put an input for example: '2..0', then print what I want as an error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide your code into input/output and calculation:

```
def conversor(anosluz):
    # just convert the given anosluz into km
    km = anosluz * (9.459 * 10**12) 
    return km


if __name__=='__main__':
    while True:
        # repeat until *break*
        anosluz = raw_input('Insira a distancia em anos luz: ')
        try:
            resultado = conversor(float(anosluz))
        except ValueError, e:
            # oh, conversor raised an exception
            print 'Ooops! O valor que inseriste nao e o correcto, tenta de novo.', e
        else:
            # no exception, print result and exit
            print resultado
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

First of you you must **not** use `input` in python2.
If you want to obtain an integer use `int(raw_input())`, otherwise use `float(raw_input())`. `input` does **not** convert a string into a number it **executes** code, so you are creating a huge hole in the security of the program using it.

An other function you might use to obtain python's built-in data types as input is [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Secondly, you can use some loop:

```
result = None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Insert number: ")
    try:
        result = float(num) * (9.459 * 10**12)
    except Exception:
        print "Try again!"
    else:
        break
print "The result is: ", result
```

Basically a `try`, `except` statement blocks the exception and let you handle it.
In your case you want to repeat the input request, and thus you should put the input request into a loop that handles the error, and let the `converser` function raise the exception.